# Maven and -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Tags: maven, utf-8

I use the following command in order to start the Maven build:

```
mvn clean install -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

So far everything works extremely fine.

I'd like to move `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` into my pom.xml in order to avoid this param at the mvn command.

In order to do this I have added the following top-level properties into the pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <file.encoding>UTF-8</file.encoding>
</properties>
```

but when I build the application with:

```
mvn clean install
```

the application fails with a following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Java Virtual Machine has not been configured to use the desired default character encoding (UTF-8).
```

So why it is working with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` and doesn't work with `<file.encoding>UTF-8</file.encoding>` ?

Comment: The exception is from runtime and not build time?

Comment: build time. I think It is something related to docker-maven-plugin and neo4j docker image

Comment: Please put the full log output there and it would be helpful to have the full pom file...I have my doubts that this output is emited by the Maven build ? FUrthermore which Maven versions do you use ?